# Exact Solution for a Nonlinear Least Squares Problem

Tags: least-squares, nonlinear-regression, nonlinear

For any linear least squares problem, we know that a unique solution always exists and that it can be explicitly written down in a closed form. My questions is that, is there any example of a nonlinear least squares problem where it is possible to write down a closed-form solution? Are there any nonlinear models known where the least squares problem can be solved explicitly, exactly, and analytically?

The more "natural" the model is (power law, gaussian, etc.), the better. And also the more parameters it has, the better. I am hoping for at least two parameters in the model. If anyone knows of a textbook example or something in a published paper with a dataset, that would be ideal.